# SparkSQL Number of Tasks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, task, scheduled-tasks, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a Spark Standalone Cluster (which consists of two Workers with  2 cores each). I run an SQLQuery which joins 2 dataframes and shows the result. I have some questions regarding the above simple example.

```
val df1 = sc.read.text(fn1).toDF()
val df2 = sc.read.text(fn2).toDF()

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("v1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("v2")
 
val df_join = sc.sql("SELECT * FROM v1,v2 WHERE v1.value=v2.value AND v2.value<1500").show()
```

**DAG Scheduler - Number of Tasks**

From what i've understood so far when i spark-submit the application, a SparkContext is spawn for the handling of the Job(where job is the printing of result rows). SparkContext creates a Task Scheduler instance which then creates a DAGScheduler. Through a simple event mechanism, the DAGScheduler handles the job for execution(*handleJobSubmitted* function from the code). SparkSQL query has been transformed into a physical execution plan(through Catalyst Optimizer), and then  to an RDD-Graph(with *toRdd* function). DagScheduler receives the RDD-Graph and recursively creates all the stages.

I do not understand how it finds the Number of Tasks(before the execution of any stage) in the last stage,keeping in mind that the result stage is the one that performs the join(and prints the results). The number of data(and the rdds and the number of their partitions, which define the number of tasks) we have is unknown until the parent stages have ended their execution.

**Parallel Execution of Stages**

Each one of the two first stages is independent of the other, as it loads data from different files. I have read many posts that say that Stages that do not have dependencies between them **MAY** be executed in parallel from the cluster. What is the condition that implies that independent stages's tasks are executed in parallel?

**Task Dependencies**

Finally, I've read that Task Scheduler **does not know about Stage Dependencies**. If I keep in mind that each Stage in Spark is a TaskSet( aka a set of non dependent tasks, each task with same functionality packed up with different partition of data), then TaskScheduler does not know as well the dependencies between tasks of different Stages.  As a result, how and when a task knows the data on which it'll execute a function?
If for example, the task knows apriori where to look for its input data, then it could be launched as soon as they become available.